# How to debug unknown javascript file?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have a website that loads a dynamically generated javascript.
The file has a different name every time, and slightly different code (some hardcoded ints). I want to hit a breakpoint on the first statement/first expression of this script, how to do that?

I'm currently using Chrome's developer tools, but any browser will do.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0XScE08hy8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Devtools (F12)
2. Click on Sources Tab
3. Select js file
4. If you don't know the name of the file, look for it on the Network Tab,
   checking the  JS option